# Post request can't fetch response from targeted page

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Writing a macro in post request when i run it, it brings unexpected response which i don't want. Perhaps it is unable to fetch response from the targeted page. Can't identify the mistake I'm doing?  The original url I'm pasting under my code.

Box to be checked before performing search:

Industry Role = Professional Services Providers

Other Criterion = APEX

```
Sub Xmlpost()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim Items As Object, Item As Object, Elem As Object
Dim postdata As String

postdata = "DoMemberSearch=1&mas_last=&mas_comp=&mas_city=&mas_stat=&mas_cntr=&mas_type=Professional+Services+Providers&OtherCriteria=1"
With http
    .Open "POST", "https://www.infocomm.org/cps/rde/xchg/infocomm/hs.xsl/memberdirectory.htm", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    .send postdata
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set Items = html.getElementById("paginationDataPool").getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Item In Items
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 1) = Item.innerText
Next Item
End Sub
```

Original Page:"https://www.infocomm.org/cps/rde/xchg/infocomm/hs.xsl/memberdirectory.htm"

Search should be made like:

[image]

The output I'm getting is this:

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me, it retrieves the member directory. What exactly is the problem? What would you expect to be different?

Comment: Thanks sir  Leviathan, for your answer. I am uploading a picture of what I'm getting in my end.

Comment: Yeah, I get the same. It looks perfectly fine to me. I repeat my question: "What would you expect to be different?"

Comment: Thanks again sir  Leviathan, for your response. If i'm right with what i have written in my code then don't you think i should get the list of names from that page. I've edited my post to fit for searching names , by the way.

Comment: Sorry sir Leviathan, you indeed right with what you said. I just checked using A tag to scrape what i get and yes it does fetch names from that target page. I wonder why the edited code can't parse names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for elements that use the class `paginationDisplayItem`, but this class is only added dynamically by JavaScript running in your browser, looking like this:

```html
<div class="paginationDisplayItem">
```

In your `html` object, however, there is just the plain HTML response from your POST request. Just save it to a file and have a look for yourself, instead of the class attribute the same `div` contains an id attribute:

```html
<div id="paginationItem_1">
```

Each successive entry has that trailing number increased by one.

If you adapt your loop to retrieve elements based on that id, everything will work as you expect.

Proof of concept:

```
For x = 1 To 57
    Set Item = html.getElementById("paginationItem_" & x)
    Cells(x, 1) = Item.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
Next x
```

You will obviously not want to explicitly loop to 57 in all cases, so feel free to refactor this to your likings.

Btw.: You should declare `Items As IHTMLElementCollection` and `Item As IHTMLElement` - this way IntelliSense will work on your objects and you'll have type safety.

Comment: I just found it what you explained here.  In fact, viewing source code is one of the important factors i should not have forgotten during writing code. Your suggestion lead me to reach there. Now, the edited code works.Thanks.